# Generate .d.ts files with webpack and angular-cli in prod folder

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Good morning;
I am using angular 4 with angular-cli and I am wondering how to generate the .d.ts files of my components in prod environnement.

In angular 2 I used this tutorial to accomplish this
https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435

package json file

```
{
  "name": "zippy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "zippy.bundle.js",
  "jsnext:main": "zippy.module.js",
  "module": "zippy.module.js",
  "types": "zippy.module.d.ts",

  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,       
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "files": [
      "./src/app/zippy.moodule.ts"
      ]
  }
}
```

and i run ng build --prod command
Cordially

Webpack config file

```
const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { GlobCopyWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";




module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src/styles.css"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
          /\/node_modules\//
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.json$/,
        "loader": "json-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "less-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
      "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "/home/riadh/WebstormProjects/zipdemo/src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
      }
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src/index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "inline",
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "vendor",
      "minChunks": (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ]
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      "filename": "[name].bundle.css",
      "disable": true
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      "sourceMap": false,
      "options": {
        "postcss": [
          autoprefixer(),
          postcssUrl({"url": (URL) => {
            // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
            if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                return URL;
            }
            if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL}`;
            }
            else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                    `/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
            else {
                // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
        }})
        ],
        "sassLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false,
          "includePaths": []
        },
        "lessLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false
        },
        "context": ""
      }
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments/environment.ts": "environments/environment.ts"
      },
      "exclude": [],
      "tsConfigPath": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true
    })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone interrested about how to build a library with angular 2/4, you will find the answer in this link

http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass --declaration flag to tsConfig file to let it generate d.ts file for corsponding js file.

[Read more on official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: @AdouaniRiadh i guess you are using ts-loader or awesome-typescript-loader in your webpack and they may not generate d.ts files for you. if you use angular/compiler-cli and then it will generate those files or just run tsc to compiler your files and you will get all but i guess you don't want other fils like js files. i would recommend you make two scripts one for compile using tsc and other for clean up all .js file

Comment: I put the webpack config file now can u plz view the config?

Comment: @AdouaniRiadh you are using ngtools/webpack plugin and that will not generate d.ts files that will do do Ahead of time compilation so your aåpp doesn't need to be compiled in run time. go for tsc compiler to generate your d.ts files.

Comment: This doesn't always work... I think tsc is the only thing that can be reliably persuaded to generate .d.ts files...